# How can I stop my user login in page from logging in without details?

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, express

Hi I'm creating an API which requires a log in system using NodeJs and a mySQL database.

I've managed to connect to my database and create a basic login page for now. However, on my log in page without even typing anything in and just pressing the log in button it redirects straight to the welcome page.

How can I fix my code so that a user has to type the correct username and password for it to log in ?

In my database the table is called users and I want to use the columns called username and password.

This is my code so far,

[code currently using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYALd.png)

```
const mysql = require("mysql2");
const express = require ("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const encoder = bodyParser.urlencoded();

const app = express();
app.use("/assets",express.static("assets")); 

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "root",
password: "root123",
database: "mydb"
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
    }

    console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');
  });

app.get("/", function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.post("/", encoder,function(req,res){
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  connection.query("select*from users where username = 
users.username and password = users.password ",
  [username, password],function(error,results,fields){
    if (results.length > 0) {
        res.redirect("/welcome");
    } else {
      res.redirect("/");
    }
    res.end();
  })
})
app.get("/welcome",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname +'/welcome.html')
})

app.listen(4500);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problems with this code, but your current issue is that your query is not checking their stored username and password against what they are typing in, it is checking them against themselves